# AJAX POST will not work loading PHP page in DIV

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

my patience with ajax is gone. no matter cannot get this working. To be honest, I have not tried this outside a DIV because the intention is specifically use AJAX to load and post a form across to a page within the confines of said DIV.

Many Thanks for the advancement of what is to come.

The #contentmainpane is a DIV. I have ...

```
if (isset($_POST['l'])) {
echo $_POST['l']; }
else { 
echo 'nope'; }
```

... in the CART page loads fine but does not receive the post from the BOOK page(so I get nope echoed on CART.PHP within #contentmainpane DIV).
Here is the offending BOOK page code:

```
<form id="form1" method="POST">
<input id="l" name="l" size="45" type="text" value="book">
<input id="submit" name="submit" value="save" type="submit">
</form>


<script>
$('#form1').submit(function(event){

event.preventDefault();

var book = $('#book').serialize();
var cart = '/content/pages/cart.php';
var formdata = {"book": book}


$.ajax({

type: "POST",

url : "/content/pages/cart.php"

data: formdata,

success: function(msg){

$("#contentmainpane").load(cart);

}
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: In your ajax parameters, try `data:book` instead of `data:formdata`. You are wrapping your post parameters in another post parameter called 'book'.

Comment: If you want to know exactly what is coming through use var_dump($_POST) in your PHP script

Comment: When you use serialize, it automatically adds the field name & value. No need to add the variable formdata

Comment: i dont know why your patience is gone and how your patience is gone.. there are plenty of things pending to do to ever make the code work.. please see the answers below, all are reasonable..

Comment: data: {'l': book} is what I have been advised. ahh. I believe I have tried every combination and permutation from different examples on the web. I have tried IE and Firefox to test.

Comment: Have you made any progress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem has been resolved**

Thank you all for your suggestions and efforts. A user on codingforums resolved this ajax post issue.

Here's the thread http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?p=1294868#post1294868

Best Regards to all coders

Answer (score 2):

I noticed you are serializing a form with an ID of #Book but your html doesnt show an ID of #book... Also, you need a comma after the url

Try This

```
$('#form1').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var book = $('#form').serialize();
    var cart = '/content/pages/cart.php';

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/content/pages/cart.php",
        data: book,
        success: function() {
            $("#contentmainpane").load(cart);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting the comma at the end of url. Yeah the # thing is required otherwise there's no output if I test with         success: function(msg) { alert(msg)            $("#contentmainpane").load(cart);}

Comment: @user1850420 Is the form you are submitting also the form which contains the data? Also, Is the PHP you have shown the only PHP your using?

Comment: Hi VIDesignz. first php page is post sending. the second(seperate from the first) php page contain <?php if (isset($_POST['l'])) {
echo $_POST['l']; }
else { 
echo 'nope'; }?>

Comment: @user1850420 Hmmm...Ok. Can you put all the html/forms in your post that are associated with what you are doing? Is the only issue that you have is getting recognition that the $_POST['l'] is set?

Answer (score 2):

Your `data` needs to be an object with an existing key of value `l`.

Since your requesting a `$_POST` value of 'l', you must pass a data object with a key 'l'. From your code, your variable `formdata` which you pass in the AJAX call is currently an `{ 'book' : book}`.

Instead it must be either `{ 'l' : book }`

OR, in your PHP code

`if(isset($_POST['book'])){...`

Comment: Thanks, it's corrected now, unfortunately the load page does not receive the post - get empty var_dump value

Answer (score 1):

You can tie PHP with jQuery through AJAX, easily, using phery library. http://phery-php-ajax.net

you didn't mention what your `#book` is, I guess it's a form right? In that case, using `data-related` in your form will make it able to join the two forms in one AJAX call.

In your case, it would be like:

```php
<form id="form1" data-remote="function" method="POST" data-related="#book">
  <input id="l" name="l" size="45" type="text" value="book">
  <input id="submit" name="submit" value="save" type="submit">
</form>
```

In your PHP it will be:

```php
function func($data){
  $r = new PheryResponse;
  // $data['l'] got what you want, also $data['submit'] is available here
  // do whatever you need to do, then update your #contentmainpane
  $r->jquery('#contentmainpane')->html('your cart.php contents');
  return $r;
}

Phery::instance()->set(array(
  'function' => 'func'
))->process();
```

your logic will be server side now, and not client side anymore. doing this way you can have much more flexibility, since the code that comes from the server is free and can be changed when needed, not the same happens with client side code.

Comment: I may consider this - just yet another something to learn. Thanks very much.

Comment: sometimes a library can do much more with much less, that is this case, you only have to worry about your true application logic, not the transport in between that is, AJAX / PHP / jQuery